# retrofit2.HttpException: HTTP 403 Forbidden

Tags: android, http, request, retrofit

I am currently making an app that fetches the data from rapid API.
but I am getting the error :

```
retrofit2.HttpException: HTTP 403 Forbidden
```

I don't know what's the problem, if anyone know the solution please help me.

This is the get request I am making :

```
interface ApiService {

@GET("product/search?")
suspend fun getResult(@Query("keyword")keyWord: String, @Query("country")country: String, @Query("category")category: String,
@Header("x-rapidapi-key")apiKey: String, @Header("x-rapidapi-host")apiHost: String): List

}
```

Comment: 403 means you don't have access, so is there even a problem here ? if you don't have auth, you don't have auth. are you passing in the correct token ? how do we know your request is valid ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `HttpLoggingInterceptor`? check it from [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor) to verify that everything has been sent well.

If everything went well, the issue is from the backend side.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the api contract?

Maybe there is an unnecessary question mark at the end of the path.

```java
@GET("product/search?")
```